# PATINDEX does not recognize dot and comma

Tags: t-sql, patindex

I have a column that should contain phone numbers but it contains whatever the user wanted. I need to create an update to remove all the characters after an invalid character.

To do this I am using a regex as `PATINDEX('%[^0-9+-/()" "]%', [MobilNr])` and it seemed to work until I had some numbers as `+1235,  36446` and to my surprise the result is 0 instead of 6. Also if the number contains `.` it returns 0.

Does `PATINDEX` ignores dot(".") and comma(",")? Are there other characters that `PATINDEX` will ignore?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. If you could [edit] your question to include sample data (As DDL+DML!), your current statement and expected results that would be great.

Comment: Why does it matter the DDL and DML? Try SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9+-/()" "]%', '+1235, 36446') and the result is 0 instead of 6 which is the index of ",". From this I undestand that PATINDEX or Regex ignores dot and comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that `PATINDEX` ignores the comma and the dot, it's your pattern that created this problem.

With `PATINDEX`, the hyphen char (`-`) has a special meaning - it's in fact an operator that denotes an inclusive range - like `0-9` denotes all digits between `0` and `9` - so when you do `+-/` it means all the chars between `+` and `/` (inclusive, of course). The comma and dot chars are within this range, that's why you get this result.

Fixing the pattern is easy: either use `|` as a logical or, or simply move the hyphen to the end of the pattern:

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9/()" "+-]%', '+1235, 36446') -- Result: 6
```